# EF inserting record to Parent and child in one shot with file upload

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can insert related child record in one shot when parent record is inserted. But if my child record is file then how can i insert and upload related child record (for file) in one shot. Where file will upload in different location not database.

Child file class :

```
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RelativePath { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Parent item insertion code :

```
public ActionResult Create(QuestionCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    var question = new Question
    {
        Text = viewModel.Text,
        QuestionType = viewModel.QuestionType,
        Answer = viewModel.Answer,
        Notes = viewModel.Notes,
        CategoryId = viewModel.CategoryId,
        Files = viewModel.Files // Also need to Upload
    };

    _questionRepository.Insert(question);
    _questionRepository.Save();

    return Json(null);
}
```

Now where i put my file upload code to upload files when insert parent and child data.

Comment: Please, rephrase your question. It's hard to understand. Be more explicit. What does "where i put my file upload code to upload files when when insert parent and child data" mean? Is it a Web API action? Is it business logic? Which parameters does it receive? What should it return?

Comment: I can upload my file using foreach on viewModel.Files after insert Question. But i want to know is their any way to upload file simultaneously like we insert child data with parent data using EntityFramework.

Comment: Please, don't answer in a comment. Edit your question, make it more understandable, so that someone can understand it.

Comment: This code should also insert `Files` (assuming that `_questionRepository.Insert` contains something like `context.Questions.Add`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it like this way : I used an extra function named `ManageFiles(Request.Files)` that upload all file then return list of uploaded files. So that when parent record insert it also upload it's child file and insert file record's in one shot.

```
public ActionResult Create(QuestionCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    var question = new Question
    {
        Text = viewModel.Text,
        QuestionType = viewModel.QuestionType,
        Answer = viewModel.Answer,
        Notes = viewModel.Notes,
        CategoryId = viewModel.CategoryId,
        Files = ManageFiles(Request.Files)
    };

    _questionRepository.Insert(question);
    _questionRepository.Save();

    return Json(null);
}

private ICollection<File> ManageFiles(HttpFileCollectionBase fileCollection)
{
    var files = new List<File>();

    for (var index = 0; index < fileCollection.Count; index++)
    {
        if (fileCollection[index] == null || fileCollection[index].ContentLength <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (UploadFile(Request.Files[index]))
        {
            var file = new File
            {
                Name = uploaded.FileName,
                RelativePath = uploaded.FilePath + uploaded.FileName,
                MimeType = uploaded.FileBase.ContentType,
                Size = uploaded.FileBase.ContentLength
            };

            files.Add(file);
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```